# Custom Gradle Plugin: Task not found when adding grgit.checkout

Tags: gradle, groovy, grgit, gradle-custom-plugin

I'm writing a custom gradle plugin. I'm working on two tasks at the moment:

```
project.tasks.create("prepareCustomTask", PrepareCustomTask) {
    it.group = TASK_GROUP
    it.description = "Prepares custom task"
}

project.tasks.create("customTask", CustomTask) {
    it.group = TASK_GROUP
    it.description = "Executes custom task"
}
```

I have debugged both a lot and found that once I add [grgit](https://ajoberstar.org/grgit/index.html) line

```
grgit.checkout(branch: "dev", startPoint: "origin/" + "dev", createBranch: true)
```

in the "PrepareCustomTask" gradle doesn't find the task "CustomTask" when executing, even though it is listed in `gradle task -all`

```
Task 'CustomTask' not found in root project
```

I'm confused about why this is happening. Can you help me?

Edit: I'm calling both tasks with

```
gradle prepareCustomTask --refresh-dependencies --stacktrace -Dorg.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.username=**** -Dorg.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.password=****
gradle customTask --refresh-dependencies --stacktrace -Dorg.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.username=**** -Dorg.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.password=****
```